# Spotify Charts scrape data

Tags: python, spotify

I want to scrape data from Spotify Charts for my Big Data projects, but since Spotify recently changed, it doesn't allow users to see the charts without logging in, my python code didn't work like before, because https://charts.spotify.com/ would redirect me to their home page instead of the link i want to scrape the data.
Any ways to get around with this, thanks.
This is my python code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib.request
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
    
    ###get all content on home_page 
    
    url='https://charts.spotify.com/charts/view/regional-global-weekly/latest'
    hsession = requests.Session() 
    hresponse = hsession.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(hresponse.content.decode('utf-8'),"html.parser")
    
    table=soup.find('table', 'Table__TableElement-hzsdh5-0 dKzsET ChartsTable__StyledTable-sc-1ye7294-5 bovxiZ')
    links = table.findAll('a')
    print(links); ###Error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help you with the scraping process, but in case you're just interested in the data itself (as I was), [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/dhruvildave/spotify-charts) dataset on Kaggle has all the chart information from 2017 up until the end of 2021.

In case you also want to scrape more recent data, you could try reaching out to the [guy who collected all that data](https://www.kaggle.com/dhruvildave).